# How to pass an HWND as a GLFWwindow*?

Tags: c++, winapi, glfw, hwnd

I have an HWND that I have been using as the target of OpenGL draw operations, and it is necessary that it be an HWND and not a GLFWwindow for other utilities of the application I'm making. The problem is, I need to load and use shaders on textures that I am rendering text to with FreeType. Unfortunately functions like `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback()` and `glfwSwapBuffers()` require a `GLFWwindow*`. Is there any way I can pass a normal HWND as a GLFWwindow?

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want to achieve? Why do you need glfw at all when you already have a HWND? How is `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback` related to render to texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When in Rome"...

Just leave your OpenGL window as `GLFWwindow`.

When (if?) you really need `HWND`, use [glfwGetWin32Window](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__native.html#gafe5079aa79038b0079fc09d5f0a8e667)

Comment: Yes I think this is the direction I'll go. I need to use HWND though because I have dropTarget calls for when a user drag and drops files, I'm not sure how else I would achieve such functionality without the use of HWND utilities.